# How do I create a custom-keying set based on a built-in keying set?

Tags: animation, rigify

While creating actions I noticed that I sometimes forgot to keyframe the IK/FK sliders separately. Therefore I decided to create a custom keying-set. The question is can I copy the setup from say LocRot into my customized keying set or do I have add each location and rotation for all bone layers separately?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties can't be added to a built-in keying-set, which isn't necessary. The keying-set *Whole Character* also includes ik/fk switch (among others).

[image]

[image]

Note that for walk cycles the keys for the root bone should be removed.

Related:

[Coding your own "Builtin Keying Set"](http://aligorith.blogspot.de/2011/02/extending-25-coding-your-own-builtin.html)