# How to keyframe IK bones?

Tags: animation, rigging

I have a rigged human character which I started to animate recently. I enabled Inverse Kinematics for the feet (chained to the root bone) and targeted them to two empties on the floor, so they would stay there. This way I can easily create animations in standing pose, for example a fight stance animation or punches (for a fighting game). 
I made several keyframes for these animations for every bone (even the IK bones targeted to the floor), expecting, I would no longer need the IK after that, but if I disable those, the legs are no longer connected to the floor if I play the animation.
So the problem is, I would like to record an animation while the feet are targeted to the floor empties, then disable targeting. The recorded animations should stay the same, because I want to create some kicks after that (so the feet would not be on the floor).
(By the way, I have tried setting keyframes with LocRot, and also Visual LocRot, which seems to be the same)

Comment: Are you using rigify or a custom IK setup? In case of rigify see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18023/how-do-i-create-a-custom-keying-set-based-on-a-built-in-keying-set

Comment: No, I am using a custom setup, the rig is set up by an artist, I am animating it. Only a few bones are set up for IK, such as the feet and the arms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I've found a solution. I can bake an animation by **Pose->Animation->Bake Action** menu, and enabling Visual Keying sub-option. It creates a whole new Action though.

If anyone has a solution how can I do this for individual keyframes, please share it and I will accept that as an answer, I will wait for a few days.